# Reading Cookie when using Curl in php, how to?

Tags: php, curl

I am connecting to an API service which authenticates users using cookies.
I make these two statements from command prompt and it works.

```
curl -d "u=username&p=password" -c ~/cookiejar https://domain/login

curl -b https://domain/getData
```

Now I want to make two equivalent php files **login.php** and **get_data.php** using curl.

I am using

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
```

in `login.php`

and

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```

in `get_data.php`

It is not working. Cookie file is getting created but second curl is not reading it.
Is this the right way to do it ? Do I have to read the cookie file seperately and set the header `Cookie` ? Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's usually best to set both cookie options, regardless of whether the script's just reading or writing the cookies.

Comment: Will header value `Cookie` be automatically added to curl request in `get_data.php` ?

Comment: if that particular curl instance can read the cookie file created by the other script, then yes.

Comment: is there any method to see the curl request headers. Can I get it from curl instance ? or is there any tool like fiddler for Mac (I am working Mac OS ) ?

Comment: hmmm. curlopt_header would include headers, but I think that's for the response only. to view the outgoing stuff, you'd need a network sniffer or a debugging proxy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will do the trick. I run it against Google.com as an example:

```
<?PHP

// open a site with cookies
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// get cookies
$cookies = array();
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:(?<cookie>\s{0,}.*)$/im', $content, $cookies);

print_r($cookies['cookie']); // show harvested cookies

// basic parsing of cookie strings (just an example)
$cookieParts = array();
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:\s{0,}(?P<name>[^=]*)=(?P<value>[^;]*).*?expires=(?P<expires>[^;]*).*?path=(?P<path>[^;]*).*?domain=(?P<domain>[^\s;]*).*?$/im', $content, $cookieParts);
print_r($cookieParts);

?>
```

See [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574530/how-to-parse-a-cookie-string) for how to effectively parse such as string.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any method to see the curl request headers. Can I get it from curl instance ? or is there any tool like fiddler for Mac (I am working Mac OS ) ?

Yes, you can get the request headers with the following:

```
<?php
  ...
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)); // request headers
?>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed when using with:`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.5.0 it looks like you can now get the cookies in one line but I only get back an empty array using this with PHP 7.1.0:

> CURLINFO_COOKIELIST - get all known cookies

```
$cookies = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
```

Comment: I'm having these issues as well, were you able to resolve them so CURLINFO_COOKIELIST outputs the cookies? For me it was working but when I recently updated via `yum update -y` the result was always empty.

Comment: Try to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, array(''));` with the first request. This solved it for me.