# PHP cURL - login and use cookies for next runs

Tags: php, curl

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if(!empty($post)){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
}
else{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$headers = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($page, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($page, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);
return $body;
```

It works great! I just wonder how long can these cookies that I'm using for multiple runs last?

How I can check that?

Comment: Why not simply try and see what happens? I would assume that the lifetime of the cookie is used, just as it was sent

Comment: Well I try multiples times to use them and it works, Im wondering can I use them tomorrow or in the next days too?

Comment: Why not simply try that?

Comment: Well yes, I'm just wondering can I predict cookies lifetime

Comment: Why do you want to predict them? Each cookie contains its own lifetime, so there's no need to guess how long a cookie is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797313/593807) should give you the cookie expiry date.

```
preg_match_all('/.*?expires=(?P<expires>[^;]*).*?$/im', $header, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

You should get date matched - a result of -1 means there was no regex match, probably because no expiry was set in the header.

Expiry date is an optional header.

Comment: Expires: -1

I have only this value in the header, what does -1 means?