# Cookie parsing in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, http, cookies

Does anyone know of an open source Java library that can fully process client-side (browser) cookies as per the latest standard ([RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)) and with full backwards compatibility to [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) and [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) (which RFC 6265 has obsoleted)?

Some approaches have been suggested in an [earlier similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574530/how-to-parse-a-cookie-string) in StackOverflow (e.g., using the Apache HttpClient library) and there is also [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/), which converts cookies into JSON.

However, the cookie "format" has numerous variations, ranging from the original specification from Netscape to contemporary "nested" key-value pairs and beyond (e.g., Internet Explorer cookie files). So, none of the above solutions seems to handle everything fully, unless one knows the exact structure of the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: this answer is incorrect. The API intended for client to parse server set-cookie.

```
java.net.HttpCookie.parse()
```

> There are 3 http cookie specifications:

```
Netscape draft
RFC 2109 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt
RFC 2965 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt
```

> HttpCookie class can accept all these 3 forms of syntax.

Comment: There is also RFC 6265, which obsoletes RFC 2965, which obsoletes RFC 2109. Internet Explorer is a totally different story, at least in some cookies.txt files that I have processed. +1 for the information you added anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I recently started the [Java Cookie project](http://github.com/js-cookie/java-cookie), which promises full compatibility with RFC 6265 and JSON/Java Data Binding.