# How to parse the 'Cookie' header into `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, parsing, cookies

I want to parse the value of the cookie header from a http request, into a `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` instance.

Example, `Cookie` in a request:

```
Cookie: HSID=AYQEVnDKrdst; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/aaa; HttpOnly
```

Does spring provided any utils to parse it easily? I don't want to parse it manually or involve some other libraries

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a cookie string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574530/how-to-parse-a-cookie-string)

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard change the question to look for a spring solution only, it's not duplicated to that question now

Comment: I'm kinda surprised it's not supposed as an MVC parameter. Might consider posting a feature request on the Spring JIRA.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard that one is about the Set-Cookie header, this question is about Cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides [`@CookieValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CookieValue.html) as an annotation for your handler method parameters. It supports both `Cookie` as a parameter type and `String` and `int`.

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to
>   an HTTP cookie. Supported for annotated handler methods in Servlet and
>   Portlet environments.
>
> The method parameter may be declared as type `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`
>   or as cookie value type (`String`, `int`, etc).

Underneath the covers, it uses [`WebUtils#getCookie`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html#getCookie-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-java.lang.String-) to parse the value into a `Cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

WebUtils offers a getCookie method - [WebUtils.getCookie](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html)

```
Cookie cookieName=WebUtils.getCookie(request,this.COOKIE_NAME);
String cookieValue = cookieName.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with Annotation in Controller Method:

```
@CookieValue("Cookie") String cookie
```

Then use Java built in parse methods:

```
String[] cookieValues = StringUtils.split(cookie, ";");
```

or with Scanner:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(cookie).useDelimiter(";");
while(scan.hasNext()){
...
}
```